# Are there any mature Binary Decision Diagram tools available?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-decision-diagram

Are there any Binary Decision Diagram (BDD) libraries for C, or other languages that are tested and have good documentation?

Answer (score 4):

Check the [BDD library from CMU](http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/~modelcheck/bdd.html).

Also, for basic reference purposes, Pre-Fascicle 1b of The Art of Computer Programming is all about BDDs. Here's a [gzipped postscript](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc1b.ps.gz) of it. Knuth has posted a number of the programs he wrote while preparing for it on [his Programs to Read page](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [CUDD](http://vlsi.colorado.edu/~fabio/CUDD/).

For some info on how to set it up in Windows environments try [this..](http://technical-recipes.com/?p=329)

Answer (score 1):

*Binary decision diagram* Wikipedia entry, in [External links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram#External_links) section, as a quite complete list of packages.

Answer (score 0):

[BDDBDDB](http://bddbddb.sourceforge.net/) is a BDD-based system for resolving logical inferences a la Prolog.  It's been used in program analysis, general game playing, and many other domains.  It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's well-known and well-maintained.